# Unable to load local files using import/require

Tags: react-native

I can't load local files (jpg, png, json...) with either

```
import img from '../../../../assets/images/myImage.png';

require('../../../../assets/images/myImage.png');
```

With `import` VS Code notifies me that the module is not found. I can't see files in folders. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you would check if file path is correct.

If file path is correct you load it simply.
(`../../../../` is bad statement for files loading.)

The step is below

Please define `package.json` file into `assets` folder.

The content of `package.json file` looks like this

```
{
    "name" : "@assets"
}
```

then you can load the file which is in `assets` folder like this

```
const img = require('@assets/images/myImage.png');
```

Comment: Ok it's working with "require" function.
Is there a way to fix the bug with "import" function ?
thanks a lot.